# Regex to match a symmetric (palindromic) text pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match a string of the form:

```
itrti
ititrtiti
itititrtititi
```

but not

```
itrtiti
ititrti
```

where the length of the pattern on either side of the 'r' is the same.

I can write (I think):

```
(it)+r(ti)+
```

but this will allow different numbers of characters on each side.

Comment: Yes, it will. You will need to capture them (like `((?:it)+)r((?:ti)+)`) and then - if there is  a match -  use a bit of code to compare the two group values.

Comment: Use either the third-party [*regex*](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library or just compare the string with its reversed version (`s == s[::-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

Test if the string is symmetrical (= palindrome), and if the entire string from the beginning to the end matches your regex of interest.

```
import re

strs = ['itrti',
        'ititrtiti',
        'itititrtititi',
        'itrtiti',
        'ititrti']

for s in strs:
    if s == s[::-1] and re.search('^(it)+r(ti)+$', s):
        print(f'ok: {s}')
    else:
        print(f'not ok: {s}')
```

Prints:

```
ok: itrti
ok: ititrtiti
ok: itititrtititi
not ok: itrtiti
not ok: ititrti
```